# How to grep older logs from all pods in K8 (-l and --since=10m not working simultaneously)

Tags: kubernetes

I have been trying to find a solution to this among the previously asked questions, but I can't find one that works for my use case (which to me seems like a general use case)

So I have a load balancer service and 5 pods in a namespace that share a label `app=abc_application`. So when I want to follow logs in all pods simultaneously, I use this

`kubectl logs -f -l app=abc_application -c abc_application_container`

Now my use case looks like this. I have a request that failed an hour back and I want to check the logs. I wanted to use the `--since=60m` argument but that doesn't work with the above command.

Is there any alternative than getting logs of individual pods? Can this command not be integrated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this with `kubectl tail` and got it working

To install `kubectl tail` -> `kubectl krew install tail`

`kubectl tail -n <namespace> -l app=abc_application --since=2h`

Answer (score 1):

you can also do the same with **logs**

```
kubectl logs <POD name> -n <Namespace name> --since-time='2021-09-21T10:00:00Z'
```

Using simple since with logs

```
kubectl logs <POD name> -n <Namespace name> --since=60h (5s, 2m, or 3h)
```

If you want to tail logs by a few line

```
kubectl logs <POD name> -n <Namespace name> --tail=200
```

If want to **grep** anything from logs

```
kubectl logs  <POD name> -n <Namespace name> | grep <string>
```

With the above command, you can pass the container name with **-c** & **-l** for label.

Reference :  https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_logs/